# snippet that prevent the user with shop manger role in woo-commerce from viewing or editing any orders except orders with (post_status=wc-processing)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles, code-snippets

I need snippet that prevent the user with shop manger role in woocommerce from viewing or editing any orders except orders with post_status=wc-processing.

I have tried most of the plugins that assigns the user roles capabilities but nothing worked out.